# Url as req.params in Express

Tags: mongodb, express, routes, url-parameters

I'd like to use express and mongo DB to find a document based off of a URL.

My Schema includes

```
bandUrl: {
        type: String
    }
```

This is my Rout inside of the Express server.

```
// Get Single Band By bandUrl
router.get('/bandUrl/:url', (req, res) => {
    quoteGenerator.find({bandUrl: req.params.url}).then(gen => res.json(gen))
})
```

I set one of the documents to have bandUrl as 'http://localhost:3000/'.

I tested the route using something other than a URL - just using a string works fine... I'd really like to use the URL though. Is there a way to do this?

Here is my fake/test route form the application..

```
const getFakeInfo = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/autoquotegenerators/bandUrl/http://localhost:3000/"`, {
            method: 'GET',
        })
        const responseData = await response.json()

        console.log(responseData)

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

I am thinking the extra slashes in the URL are whats causing the issue.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to you use is `encodeURIComponent()`. This function escapes all URI specific characters, so they get interpreted properly. Your request code should look something like this:

```
const response = await fetch(`/api/autoquotegenerators/bandUrl/${encodeURIComponent("http://localhost:3000/")}`, {
    method: 'GET',
})
```

If you want to learn more about this function, you can have a look over [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).